# How to get more than four columns in orbeon form?

Tags: orbeon, xforms, sap-commerce-cloud

How to get more than four columns in orbeon form ? I need eight columns instead. I am using yforms which has integration with Hybris.

[image: Example with four columns]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your post to make the image visible in your question. However, you should also add you code or any information on what you have tried already. This will make it easier for others to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Not sure this question related to Hybris. Orbeon - is a 3rd party service which should be configured outside of Hybris, i.e. in Orbeon account console

Comment: @arsen_adzhiametov Hybris/SAP has an integration with Orbeon Forms and the OP is probably using that.

Comment: @ebruchez Yes, of course, Hybris Web probably use Orbeon iframe, however there should not be something specific to Hybris. I had similar integration on Hybris with 3rd party forms, and they were configured from their account profile

Comment: @ebruchez   Can we send Arabic data instead of English and store in local database in above UI form ?

Comment: Orbeon Forms handles all data in UTF-8 and so Arabic should not be a problem from that point of view. If you want right-to-left support in Form Runner, we implemented [this fix](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3305) which will ship in Orbeon Forms 2017.2.

Comment: @ebruchez  Does yForms Supports attchments ?

Comment: I believe that SAP has been working on it. If you send an email to Orbeon I can confirm the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [following property](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-builder.html#maximum-number-of-columns):

```
<property
    as="xs:integer"
    name="oxf.fb.grid.max-columns"
    value="8"/>
```

Note that the form layout with many columns can be challenging as columns become very narrow.

Comment: Can you tell me where to add this property ? I mean in which file ?

Comment: It goes in [your `properties-local.xml`](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/).